# How to include SqlExpresss 2008 (conveniently)

Tags: .net, sql-server, installation, sql-server-express, prerequisites

When I make a setup project in VS 2008, and select <Setup Project>, Properties, PreRequisites then i can select SqlExpress2005 to be automatically included.

What I am looking for is a walkthrough of how to get SqlExpress2008 included in the same manner.

Second choice would be how to get (or make) a MergeModule (MSM) file to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to get the bootstrapper installed.  The [recommended procedure](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2008/09/12/faq-installing-the-sql-server-2008-express-clickonce-bootstrapper-for-visual-studio-2008-sp1.aspx) for doing so it pretty idiotic.

Comment: That must be the 1 link I couldn't find yesterday. Pretty eccentric indeed, but not impossible. I'll start downloading VS Express.